# How do I mimick the Lollipop (Material Design) button animation?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, material-design

There's a style called `Widget.Material.Button` that has an animation effect that I really like (it makes a "splash" around your click), and I want to be able to reuse it in my code.

I'm trying to make it have a transparent background color, since it is gray by default which does not look good when applied to my `ViewGroup` objects.

Is there an easy way to keep the animation, but get rid of the background color?

I already tried setting the property `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`, but that causes the animation to completely stop working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, world!"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is just another line of text."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this blog](http://code.hootsuite.com/tips-and-tricks-for-android-material-support-library-2-electric-boogaloo/) under 'Clickable Views', you can use `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect, the link provided was quite informative as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for giving the wrong bit initially. The problem as looking a bit deeper is the background color is defined already as part of whatever you are using for your MaterialTheme extension for color highlights. Ironically, they have sources from transparent elsewhere but not here ?

What you want to so is make TWO new xml files to define your properties

In vales-v21/styles.xml you can redefine these any way you like or eliminate values you don't want to override

IF YOU JUST WANT THE RIPPLE, USE THE DRAWABLE CODE DEFINED AT THE BOTTOM

```
 <style name="MyMaterialButton" parent=android:Widget.Material.Button>
        <item name="background">@drawable/material_background_ripple</item>
        <item name="textAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceButton</item>
        <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="minWidth">88dip</item>
        <item name="stateListAnimator">@anim/button_state_list_anim_material</item>
        <item name="focusable">true</item>
        <item name="clickable">true</item>
        <item name="gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    </style>
```

Then your button background style 
/drawable-v21/material_background_ripple.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@android:color/PICK_RIPPLE_COLOR_HERE">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape" />
</ripple>
```

**Redacted:**
Have you tried 
customView.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.transparent);

?

Comment: There is no such method called `getWindow()` for `View` objects. I already tried setting the background color programatically, it does not work. Setting the background color of the `Activity`'s window doesn't help either.

Comment: Please read above. I think I initially misunderstood your question.